# Problem in importing the CSV file containing multiple commas in a sigle field

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I am having an issue with importing a large(60MB) CSV file in MYSQL DB.
The problem arises when an address field has multiple comma seperated values e.g. home no, street no, town etc.

I tried to use BigDump for it but, the problem did not solved because of a single field containing multiple comma separated values.

Any idea, suggestion or solution from experts how to handle it?
Please reply, because I am sick of it.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is the address enclosed in double-quotes? Like:

```
Name,Address,Email
John Smith,"123 Elm Street,New York,NY",john.smith@gmail.com
```

If it's not enclosed in double-quotes but contains commas, it's not a valid CSV file.

Comment: I am watching this file in excel and it is not enclosed in any double-quotes.

Comment: Looking at it in excel isn't ideal, open it in a text editor. Edit a few lines into your question, it's hard to help without knowing exactly what you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have looked at it in notepad and this address values are enclosed in double-quotes, just like the example you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement. It allows you to carefully control the CSV dialect.